# Express-Cassandra OperationTimedOutError while creating tables

Tags: node.js, cassandra, express-cassandra

I am using express-Cassandra ORM and DB operation with Cassandra.

Env:
version: 2.1.1
nodejs 8.9.1
cassandra : 3.9
Cent OS: 6.0

Facing this issue, when running nodejs while initializing models in Cassandra and I need to restart nodejs multiple time to initialize all the modules.

> Getting timeout error: cause: {
>   apollo.model.tablecreation.dbindexcreate: Error while creating index
>   on DB Table -> NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query
>   failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: OperationTimedOutError: The
>   host 127.0.0.1:9042 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms. See
>   innerErrors

So after restart mulitpel time I am able to complete cassandra initialisation.

and How can I resolve this or how can I find where are more logs and what is this inner error?

Thanks,
James

Comment: looks like it's taking more time to complete the indexing than the timeout specified in your cassandra config, you may have a look at `request_timeout_in_ms` in your cassandra.yml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use `socketOptions.readTimeout` in your clientOptions like the following:

```
models.setDirectory( __dirname + '/models').bind({
    clientOptions: {
        contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'],
        protocolOptions: { port: 9042 },
        keyspace: 'mykeyspace',
        queryOptions: { consistency: models.consistencies.one },
        socketOptions: { readTimeout: 0 }
    },
    ormOptions: {
        defaultReplicationStrategy : {
            class: 'SimpleStrategy',
            replication_factor: 1
        },
        migration: 'safe'
    }
},
function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

You may have a look at this discussion: https://github.com/masumsoft/express-cassandra/issues/156