# Getting apollo.model.save.dberror using Express Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, express-cassandra, datastax-node-driver

I am currently using **Cassandra 3.11**  having 3 node cluster & consistency of one, along with NodeJS **express cassandra client 2.3.0**. I am using the method `saveAsync` for storing the model data. But I am getting an error : `apollo.model.save.dberror`

```
Error during save query on DB -> NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query failed. \
  First host tried, <ip>:<port>: OperationTimedOutError: The host <ip>:<port> \
  did not reply before timeout 12000 ms.
```

I am unable to verify what is causing this error. This happens for most of the records & only few of them are getting through. I am inserting this data reading from a kafka topic & pushing it to cassandra after few validations. The data rate is around 200 per second.

Tried googling & searching in stack-overflow but unable to get any details around it. Sample code.

```
SomeData.insert = function (data) {
  data = transformData(data); // Basically cleans & normalizes the data to suit the model
  let any_data = new ExpressCassandra.instance.data_store(data);
  return any_data.saveAsync()
    .catch(function(err){
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you post the error description for "apollo.model.save.dberror"? Without it it's difficult to guess what happened.

Comment: @Masum : The description is this: Error during save query on DB -> NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, <ip>:<port>: OperationTimedOutError: The host <ip>:<port> did not reply before timeout 12000 ms.

The host seems all ok as we do not have any issues from the server side. Also when we check for a single message (item) to be inserted it works well.

Comment: @Masum Any information that you have on this?

Comment: have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156978/express-cassandra-operationtimedouterror-while-creating-tables

Comment: Thanks @Masum. I ll take a look & get back.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js driver returns `NoHostAvailableError` after it has tried all hosts and none of them were available.

The `OperationTimedOutError` means that driver attempted to contact a node but never got a reply. This is a different error to a read or write timeout which is a response returned by the coordinator node.

`OperationTimedOutError` indicates that the nodes are unresponsive, usually because they are overloaded. You will need to review the logs and if you're seeing lots of GC activity and/or lots of dropped mutations/reads/messages then the nodes cannot keep up with the load and you need to consider increasing the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes. Cheers!